# servlet for implementing socket connection

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, sockets

How do I implement a web application with a Servlet that is listening on a port for socket connections?

Comment: btw, what language is the remote client written in? If you are using Java in the remote client, it might be better to use RMI or even remote EJB calls.

Comment: Yes! the client is written in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't mean the front-door HTTP connection, which you get for free with the servlet container... But if you want to add, say, an admin service you could create a listener thread that sets some global state in the servlet. Note that this is not considered kosher (and I believe may even violate the servlet standard).

Comment: I have a remote client and would not like to use HTTP but TCP sockets to connect to my server, therefore I would like my servlet to create some kind of serverSocket and listen for client requests for socket connections.

Comment: Servlets are very specifically an HTTP standard. If you don't want HTTP, you shouldn't use servlets - just write a custom client/server application, as Helen suggets.

Comment: Edit: as Helen & Vineet both suggest. Credit where credit is due... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Having the servlet open ServerSockets is a bad code smell. This is primarily because it is the container's responsibility to manage sockets (among other resources like worker threads, sessions etc).

That said, I do not think you need a servlet in the first place. Unless you want to access some of the container's services, it would be better if you use a J2SE application to manage ServerSockets.

Comment: What would I then need to implement this? Any code example? I have looked in client/server example posted above. Is that the way to go?

Comment: "It Depends!!". It is easy to come up with a server application using J2SE, as long as you dont botch up anything related to what a J2EE/JEE container provides out of the box. If you ever have to deal with transaction management, state management, thread pools etc., take a look at a HTTP based message exchange format, and use servlets. Eventually, it is depends on what you need your server to do.

Answer (score 2):

Not totally sure what you want to achieve, but you can have a look at [client/server programming](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/) if that's what you need. Other than that, you could implement your web application as normal but change the default port to whatever suits your need.

Comment: Refer to my written to Greg, I need something similar to client/server programming but can I implement it with servlets or would I have to go some other way.